# Trying to store Parent ID of a parent folder for a Child Folder in firebase based React App

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a react app functionality where I can create folder inside a folder,
for that I need to store parentID of the main folder in the firestore.

```
// Here is my AddFolderButton functionalty.

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFolderPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { database, db } from "../../firebase";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import {
   getFirestore,
   collection,
   getDocs,
   addDoc,
   serverTimestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function AddFolderButton({ currentFolder }) {
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
   const [name, setName] = useState("");
   const { currentUser } = useAuth();

   function openModal() {
       setOpen(true);
   }

   function closeModal() {
       setOpen(false);
   }

   function handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       try {
           if (currentFolder == null) return;
           const parentId = currentFolder?.id || null;

           console.log("Database folders:", database.folders);
           const folderRef = addDoc((database.folders), {
               name: name,
               parentId,
               userId: currentUser.uid,
               
               createdAt: serverTimestamp()
           });

           console.log(folderRef.id);
           setName("");
           closeModal();
       } catch (error) {
           console.error("Error adding folder to Firestore:", error.message);
           closeModal();
       }
   }

   return (
       <>
           <Button onClick={openModal} variant="outline-success" size="sm">
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolderPlus} />
           </Button>
           <Modal show={open} onHide={closeModal}>
               <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   <Modal.Body>
                       <Form.Group>
                           <Form.Label>Folder Name</Form.Label>
                           <Form.Control
                               type="text"
                               required
                               value={name}
                               onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                           />
                       </Form.Group>
                   </Modal.Body>
                   <Modal.Footer>
                       <Button variant="secondary" onClick={closeModal}>
                           Close
                       </Button>
                       <Button variant="success" type="submit">
                           Add Folder
                       </Button>
                   </Modal.Footer>
               </Form>
           </Modal>
       </>
   );
}
```

Here is my firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
   //creds
})

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const database = {
  folders: collection(db, 'folders'),
  files: collection(db, 'files'),
  formatDoc: (doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }),
  getCurrentTimestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};

export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

Although I am not sure with the syntax is fine or not? Because in some stackoverflow post I saw some other `**" .id"**` and Is using `.id` a correct way?

Comment: I'm not clear what it is you are asking?  Does the above code work?  If not, then tell us what are you EXPECTING it to do, and what it is ACTUALLY doing.

Comment: Actually the above code shows no error. But what I wanted was That it should store parentId in my firestore database so that I caan ahead with making a folder inside a folder. But It is not storing the parentId

Comment: `addDoc()` returns a Promise.  You either want to `.then()` it or better yet make the function you are calling it from an `async` function and then `await addDoc(....)`